# Is it possible to perform atomic updates using Dropbox API?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Does Dropbox API provide check-and-swap type of operation or any other way to ensure that when I'm updating a file - I'm updating the version of the file that I specified and not overwriting someone else's changes in a race-condition?

For example some APIs support [`If-Match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Match) header for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, when uploading files via the Dropbox API, the way to do this is to use the `update` `WriteMode`, and supply the `rev` value of the version of the file you want to write on top of:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload

If it doesn't match, the API will return a conflict instead of overwriting someone else's changes.

You can get the `rev` value for the version you're updating from wherever you received that version of the file via the API, e.g., from the download endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download